# Trigger event on parent click but not on children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a parent div that is positioned absolutely and then a child div that has a higher z-index and is positioned relatively, is there a way to have a click event register only if the parent div is clicked, but not the inside div?

[Relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bt5HA/)

[Updated fiddle with text input example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bt5HA/1/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$(".parent").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Bt5HA/4/

Comment: Minor detail, but why not use strict equality?

Comment: @m59 There is no difference when you compare references, otherwise possible nano difference in speed is not important in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
$('.child a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent('.child').hide();
});​
```

Comment: That only works if the child is clicked. What happens if the parent is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Access child elements and return false when they're clicked http://jsfiddle.net/Bt5HA/3/

Comment: VisioN has the best solution, ignore this post

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('#child').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
alert('You clicked Child');
});


$('#parent').click(function() {
alert('You clicked on Parent');
});
```

You can check working here
http://jsfiddle.net/VnHGh/24/